# Placing labels inside pie chart slices (Highchart)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, pie-chart

Using Highchart. I am positioning the labels inside the slices using distance and it centers well on mobile, but not on tablets or desktops. As the dimensions become larger, the labels get too close to the edges. How to position labels depending on viewport dimensions?

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: "pointer",
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: "<strong>{point.name}</strong><br>{point.percentage:.0f}%",
            distance: -60,
            color: "white"
        }
    },

series: [ {
            type: "pie",
            data: [
                {
                    name: "Not too much text here",
                    color: "#5cb85c",
                    y: 35
                },
                {
                    name: "Not too much text here",
                    color: "#5bc0de",
                    y: 30
                },
                {
                    name: "Less text here",
                    color: "#78629b",
                    y: 15
                },
                {
                    name: "Less text here",
                    color: "#f0ad4e",
                    y: 10
                },
                {
                    name: "Less text here",
                    color: "#d9534f",
                    y: 10
                }
            ]
        } ]
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/TimNguyenBSM/rL1bwam6/1/

Comment: Do you have a complete JSFiddle?

Comment: @Ondkloss http://jsfiddle.net/TimNguyenBSM/rL1bwam6/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a variable for the `distance`-option which you've prepared beforehand. For example:

```
var windowSize = $(window).width();
var distance = -60;

if(windowSize > 700)
    distance -= 30;
// else if...
```

And in your `plotOptions.pie.dataLabels`:

```
distance: distance
```

Comment: I think that is a good solution. I was hoping that I was using Highcharts incorrectly and there was a built in option out there?

Comment: I agree. It's far from optimal. As far as I can see there's no options that makes this straight forward. Also, since it's a plotOption it's not easy to change after rendering either. Hopefully someone finds something more solid, but at least this is a possible fix. You could of course also use your container-width, if that is a more relevant metric for the distance-value.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to use this solution for now, but leave this open for a few days to see if there are any new solutions.