# How to change the dataLabels of highchart to new position?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to change the dataLabels of highchart  to new position like this images?
[i want to change to this position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uySy.png)

thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/ruagiahanoi/6180x5n0/

```
y: 58,
        dataLabelss: { x: 0, y: -100 },
        color: '#8aea0f',
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Firefox versions',
            categories: ['美元 v31', '澳元 v32'],
            data: [29,29],
            color: ['#0078b4', '#035a82']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be achieved in different ways. One, which I have taken [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39915448/2381339), comes here.

http://jsfiddle.net/6180x5n0/1/

```
var positionLabels = function(chart) {
    var series = chart.series[0],
      dataLabelsGroup = series.dataLabelsGroup,
      xVal;
    Highcharts.each(dataLabelsGroup.element.children, function(d) {
      xVal = (d.attributes.transform.value).substring((d.attributes.transform.value).indexOf('(') + 1, (d.attributes.transform.value).indexOf(','));
      $(d).attr('transform', 'translate(' + xVal + ',135)')
    })
  };
```

Note that this function adds 135px to the y coordinates of the data labels.

You need to change the properties of the chart accordingly:

```
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            events: {
        load: function() {
          positionLabels(this)
        },
        redraw: function() {
          positionLabels(this)
        }
      },
        },
```

As an alternative, you might simply want to set the `y` coordinate of the data series labels to `0` ([see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6180x5n0/2/)). This will make the chart more flexible when redrawing:

```
           dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                },
                color: '#ffffff',
                distance: -70,
                y: 0
            }
```

For further reading, you might be interested in this:

[Placing labels inside pie chart slices (Highchart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334551/placing-labels-inside-pie-chart-slices-highchart)